# Spliting lists into equal parts

Tags: python

Also,

people = ['paul', 'francois', 'andrew', 'sue', 'steve', 'arnold', 'tom', 'danny',
          'nick', 'anna', 'dan', 'diane', 'michelle', 'jermy', 'karen']

num_teams = 4

L should contain 4 sublists containing elements indices in 0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3 format

```
 def form teams(people, num_teams):

   '''make num_teams teams out of the names in list people by counting off. people in a list of people's name(strs) and num_teams(an int >= 1) is the desired
   number of teams. Return a list of lists of names, each sublist representing a team.'''

 L= []
# Make an outer list
 for i in range(num_teams):
       L.append([])
# make an i th number of sublist according to the range

for team in range(num_teams) #in this case 0,1,2,3
      for i in range(0, len(people), num_teams) #start from 0 to len(people) which in this case is 15 and  by taking 0,1,2,3, steps 
          if (team + i) < len(people): <---??????
               L[team].append(people[team+i]) <---??????

 return L
 print(L)

 [['paul', 'steve', 'nick', 'michelle'],['francois','arnold','anna','jeremy'],     ['andrew','tom','dan','karen'],['sue','danny','diane']
```

Can someone please explain ones I placed? On it and am I getting concepts correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are trying to achieve, but maybe this serves your purpose:

```
print ( [ [x for i, x in enumerate (people) if i % num_teams == y] for y in range (num_teams) ] )
```

Using your people array and num_teams = 4, this outputs:

```
[['paul', 'steve', 'nick', 'michelle'], ['francois', 'arnold', 'anna', 'jermy'], ['andrew', 'tom', 'dan', 'karen'], ['sue', 'danny', 'diane']]
```

With num_teams = 3, the output is:

```
[['paul', 'sue', 'tom', 'anna', 'michelle'], ['francois', 'steve', 'danny', 'dan', 'jermy'], ['andrew', 'arnold', 'nick', 'diane', 'karen']]
```

.

**EDIT: The 6 question marks**

The first line marked with question marks checks to see if `team + i` is within the bounds of the list `people`, in order to make sure that in the next like `people[team+i]` doesn't fail.

The second line marked with question marks appends the element at position `team+i` from the list `people` to the list of the corresponding team. As i takes at num_teams-wide steps, you get into the first team (with index 0) the 0th, num_teams-th, 2num_teams-th, etc person, in the second team (with index 1) the 1st, (num_teams+1)-th, (2num_teams+1)-the, etc person, and so on for all teams.

But please, do not use this code. It overcomplicates things. The whole function of the code you posted can be expressed much more clearly.

.

**EDIT 2:**

The algorithm you would apply as a human is to line up all people in a row and pass before them counting 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0... (as you already stated). You can implement this expressively like this:

```
def makeTeams (people, teamCount):
    teams = []
    for i in range (teamCount): teams.append ( [] )

    #You can write the above two lines as this: teams = [ [] for x in range (teamCount) ]

    curTeam = 0
    #Now walk past the line of people:
    for person in people:
        #Add person to current team
        teams [curTeam].append (person)
        #Add 1 to the team index
        curTeam += 1
        #If you have counted too far, set the current Team to 0
        if curTeam == teamCount: curTeam = 0
        #The two lines above, can be written as curTeam = (curTeam + 1) % teamCount

    return teams
```

Or you make use of python's generators (which are a forte of python):

```
makeTeams = lambda people, teamCount: [ [person for i, person in enumerate (people) if i % teamCount == team] for team in range (teamCount) ]
```